# Server side available HTTP methods

Tags: php, http

Its possible to know available HTTP methods on server side from PHP script?

I know i can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] global variable to know method for the current request, but i don't want this, if not, the available methods on Apache HTTPD or Nginx servers.

Comment: You might take a look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_allowmethods.html . Unless used, it doesn't look like apache limits at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's no environment variable that is set, or any server-agnostic way to determine the available request methods that PHP would be aware of.  In order to make this determination, you'd have to setup PHP as a client using cURL to make various requests to the server to see if they're allowed.  Something like this (untested):

```
$methods = array( 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'CONNECT' );

foreach ( $methods as $method ) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost' );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method );

    curl_exec($ch);

    if ( curl_errno( $ch ) == 405 ) {
        echo "Method $method not allowed.";
    } else {
        echo "Method $method allowed.";
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Specifically, I have not tested this to make sure that 405 is consistently returned when calling against a server that does not allow the requested method.  So you'll want to double-check that.  But this should give you a good idea.  Since you're making seven HTTP calls when this runs, you may not want to run it on every page load, but rather just occasionally and then cache the results.  It's unlikely that the allowed methods will change frequently.